# How do I get the id of a document that contains a certain field that I want?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I gave all of the documents random id numbers. I want to get the spcific document id if the document contains a certain field. In my case, I have a locations field and if the document contains Tokyo, Japan, I want the code to automatically post a new document into the subcollection of the document that contains the same location.

[image]

I tried writing my own code like this:

```
  onPressed: () async {
          final bool placeExists = await checkIfPlaceExists(address);

          if (!placeExists) {
            if (areAllFieldsEmpty()) {
              showMissingFieldsSnackBar();
            } else {
              postImage(
                currentUser!.uid,
                currentUser!.username,
                currentUser!.photoUrl,
                currentUser!.faculty,
              );
            }
          } else {
            postSubPost(
              currentUser!.uid,
              currentUser!.username,
              currentUser!.photoUrl,
              currentUser!.faculty,
            );
          }
        },
```

it works but the subcollection makes a whole new document and then makes a subcollection into the new document instead of the existing document

```
Future<String> uploadSubPost(
  String description,
  List<Uint8List>? file,
  String uid,
  String username,
  String profImage,
  double rating,
  String title,
  String time,
  String faculty,
  double moneyRating,
  String address,
  String selectedPlace,
  String parentPostId, // Add a parameter to specify the parent post ID
  ) async {
String res = "Some error occurred";
try {
  List<String> downloadUrls =
  await StorageMethods().uploadImagesToStorage('subposts', file, true);
  String photoUrl = downloadUrls
      .join(',\n'); // Join the URLs with a delimiter of your choice
  String subPostId = const Uuid().v1(); // creates unique id based on time
  subPost subpost = subPost(
    description: description,
    uid: uid,
    username: username,
    faculty: faculty,
    bookmark: [],
    postId: subPostId,
    datePublished: DateTime.now(),
    postUrl: photoUrl,
    profImage: profImage,
    rating: rating,
    title: title,
    time: time,
    moneyRating: moneyRating,
    address: address,
    selectedPlace: selectedPlace,
  );

  // Reference the parent post document and its subcollection
  final DocumentReference parentPostRef =
  _firestore.collection('posts').doc(parentPostId);
  final CollectionReference subCollectionRef =
  parentPostRef.collection('subposts');

  // Add the data to the subcollection
  await subCollectionRef.doc(subPostId).set(subpost.toJson());

  res = "success";
} catch (err) {
  res = err.toString();
}
return res;
```

}

so I wrote this code but I do not know how to get the post id of a document that already contains the address. How do I change the code to make this happen? Please tell me if anything is unclear.

Comment: It looks like you'll want to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) for that.